# how to add headers to other php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, data-structures

Here's the original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ID
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => GROUP
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1221
            [1] => 500
            [2] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1654
            [1] => 33
            [2] => 23
        )
)
```

Covert it to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID]    => 1221
            [NAME]  => 500
            [GROUP] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID]    => 1654
            [NAME]  => 33
            [GROUP] => 23
        )
)
```

Of course there's more than 3 headers and more than 2 arrays of data. Is there an automatic way to do this efficiently and cleanly?

Comment: `array_combine()` does this, but you'll need to iterate over the array and call it for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
$keys = array_shift($data);
$data = array_map(function ($v) use($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $v);
}, $data);

print_r($data);
```

[Live DEMO](https://eval.in/36328)

Answer (score 1):

```
$header = $array[0];
$newarray = array();
for($i = 1; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    $newarray[$i-1] = array();
    foreach($header as $k => $v) {
        $newarray[$i-1][$v] = $array[$i][$k];
    }
}


print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer to this question is to use PHP built-in functions like `array_values`, `array_fill`, `array_combine` and `array_map`:

**Working example**: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zdw-v9k

```
function array_mapper($keys, $record) {
    return array_combine($keys, $record);
}

$key = array_values(array_shift($arr));
$keys = array_fill(0, count($arr), $key);
$res = array_map('array_mapper', $keys, $arr);

print_r($res);
```